# Long description for a directory

Tags: directory, filemanager, metadata

I store my images in this structure:

```
YYYY/MM/DD-foo
```

`-foo` is optional and a short description of the event.

Sometimes I would like to store a **long description** for this directory.

I think the answer "You can use programm X for your images" does not help.

I would like to have a solution that works for directories containing text or audio files, too.

Question: How to give a directory a long description? A description which can contain newlines and other characters like a slash?

**Update**

> And you can't simply store text files with descriptions in the directories?

Yes I could do this. But I thought there is already a convention or specification for this.

I would love to see this in nautilus:

- 01-short-directory-name, Long and verbose Text,
- 02-short-directory-name, Long and verbose Text2,
- ...

I could not find a meta-data spec for directories myself.

## Needed features

- Backup with `rsync`, `tar`, dropbox or owncloud should work.
- Text should allow to contain any unicode character.
- Arbitrary key value mapping (like json)
- Common solution, not a self made script hack.

Comment: And you can't simply store text files with descriptions in the directories?

Comment: try putting the description between " " so you get
YYYY/MM/DD-"first image of the second month of the third year"

Comment: @techraf I updated the question. Please ask if something is not clear. Thank you.

Comment: @guettli I have read your question and comments under Rinzwinds answer. This approach  is very very troublesome, and especially since you're setting this up for non-technical users, too. I strongly suggest you abandon this idea of having special chars in filename. That said, I can offer the following: How about a right-click option that will display a popup message with description ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rinzwind has already presented reasons why slashes and other special characters are not desirable in filenames and directory names. My answer presents a simple workaround via Nautilus scripts.

#### Introduction

The following script relies on existence of `.directory_description` file in each directory ( note the leading dot ). If the file doesn't exist user will be prompted to create one.

Advantages of this approach are:

1. Simple to use : `.directory_description` is just text file, therefore simply editable via text editor. It's just right click action, so even non-technical user can use it.
2. Description is part of directory, so when properly backing up directory ( with inclusion of all files, including the dot files) , the description will be backed up as well.

#### Obtaining the script

The script is available as part of  my [github repository](https://github.com/SergKolo/nautilus_scripts) as well as below. For those who have `git` installed, use the following steps in terminal.

1. `cd ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`
2. `git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/nautilus_scripts`

Those who do not have `git` follow these steps:

1. copy the source code directly from this answer.
2. Save the code as `~/.local/share/nautius/scripts/read_dir_description.py` file.
3. Ensure it is executable with `chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautius/scripts/read_dir_description.py`

Now, every time you right click on directory and go to `scripts` menu, you will be able to run `read_dir_description.py` on that directory.

#### Script source code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Author: Serg Kolo
Date: Aug 16,2016
Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/809925/295286
"""
import subprocess
import sys
import os.path

def display_file(textfile):
    """ Displays file containing
        directory description if 
        the file exists
    """
    subprocess.call([
                    'zenity', 
                    '--text-info', 
                    '--filename=' + textfile
                    ])

def create_file(textfile):
    """ Creates text file containing
        directory description
        if the description doesn't exist
    """
    try:
        err_text = '"This directory doesn\'t have description.' +\
                   'Would you like to create one now?"'
        subprocess.check_call([
                              'zenity',
                              '--error',
                              '--text=' + err_text
                              ])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        sys.exit()

    # ensure we create the file
    with open(textfile,'w') as text:
        text.write('')                

    try:
         
        output = subprocess.check_output([
                           'zenity', 
                           '--text-info', 
                           '--editable',
                           '--filename=' + textfile
                           ])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        sys.exit()

    with open(textfile,'w') as text:
        text.write(output.decode())
                              


def main():

    file_name = '.directory_description'
    directory = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
    
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        display_file(file_path)
    else:
        create_file(file_path )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Script in Action

*Accessing the script via right click*

[image]

---

*Dialog notifying that description doesn't exist*

[image]

---

*Sample directory description*

[image]

---

Comment: Yes, I guess storing the meta data in a file `.directory_description` works. Sad, that there is no common standard.

Comment: @guettli there isn't one right now , unfortunatelly, but you could always open feature request for such feature on launchpad page for Nautilus :)

Comment: @Serg Nice script. Works in Thunar too.

Comment: @Serg I could not find a matching page at launchpad. I create an issue here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=770144

Comment: @guettli that's good i guess. Launchpad is here :https://launchpad.net/nautilus

Comment: @Serg I have seen this launchpad page of nautilus, but for me (yes, I am logged in), the report-bug or ask-question links/buttons are disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Extended File Attributes. After installing the package `attr` you can do e.g. something like this:

```
setfattr -n user.comment -v "this is a comment" directory_name
```

and read it with:

```
getfattr -n user.comment directory_name
```

According to [this site](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/pages/extattrs.html) there is a package called `eiciel`which integrates in Nautilus.

Slashes and other ASCII characters are not a problem, however other characters can be tricky, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138768/what-is-this-seemingly-base64-data-set-by-setfattr.

`rsync`, `cp`, `scp`and probably most other standard tools either preserve extended attributes or have an option to preserve it.

Comment: Big question is, can you add slashes and special characters to it ? Also, is it possible for non-techie users to access those comments in easy maner ?

Comment: Next question: Do these attributes survive rsync, cp, scp ...?